# Как сайт узнаёт email?

Tags: javascript, storage

Всем привет! Есть сайт, в нем есть удобная функция сохранения email и вывода его в input что-бы пользователь не вводил его каждый раз по новой. Ввел я email, и функция работает, но потом я очистил куки, а email остался! Я решил очистить storage, и это все равно не помогло. Кажись я нашел что-то, чего не знаю про js, хотелось бы узнать как они это сделали? Линк на сайт: <quickchange.cc>
Так же сайт выдает сообщение что я уже зарегистрирован, и могу войти в аккаунт:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что проверено: storage, cookie, fingeprint, автозаполнение форм, ip
После тестов в Sphere browser стало ясно что сайт сохраняет данные куда-то в store local data, но как это очистить в chrome?

Comment: Скорее всего это запись поля относительно "отпечатка пальца" (fingerprint) на стороне сервера. Потому что, если открыть в приватном окне, то не сохраняется. Следовательно, можно предположить, что это работа сессий на стороне сервера (например, PHP).

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Но я очистил автозаполнение в браузере, и установил расширение для подмены fingerprint, и все равно данные остались в форме..

Comment: Вероятнее всего это Local Storage

Comment: Это я уже понял, но как его очистить, или хотя бы получить доступ. Очистка через инструменты разработчика в хроме не помогает

Comment: Это может быть indexed DB или web SQL.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/10tgxf1